# Enable Google Cloud Identity Platform Programmatically (No UI)

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, automation

I have been stuck on this for a few days now. I am in the process of automating the creation of our dev stack using Pulumi. One of the Cloud Services required is Google Cloud Identity Platform. I cannot for the life of me figure out what REST API call will enable it.

From a programming point of vue, I can enable `identitytoolkit` without issue, but the `Identity Provider` service will not be enabled.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I have a suspicion that it is `Firebase Authentication` under the hood. If so, what is the API call needed to enable the service?

Comment: Looks like it's not currently possible: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186147991#comment6

Comment: Also note this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194945691